# Textbox. ngModel + initial value = no initial value.?

Tags: html, angularjs, textbox

I have a HTML textbox.

It has an ng-model, and an initial value.

The initial value is retrieved from a function, called *initialValue*().

**Problem**: Initial value doesn't get set when there's an ng-model present (see JSFiddle's Textbox1 and Textbox2), but there *needs to be an ng-model AND an initial value via function* for the textbox.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textInput" value="{{initialValue('textbox')}}" />
```

**How do I set an initial value for Textbox1 (which has an ng-model)?**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vV7Dw/1/

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a value attribute at all.  Initialize your data in the controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/PpaQ7/

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textInput"/>

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.textInput = 'hi there';
}
```

Comment: Easy, but I can't have that in this situation. (My textbox's initial value changes dynamically.)

Comment: You will need to modify $scope.textInput when you need to change the current value of the input.  If it varies based on other variables in the $scope, use the $watch function to update it.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if you could give me an idea of what causes the initial value to change.

Comment: To be honest Karl, I was making a JSFiddle for a different question, but stumbled onto this problem... and thus the creation of this question.

Comment: I don't get why the input can't have an ng-model AND an initial value.

Comment: Once you attach a model to an input, that's a two way binding.. You update the input by setting the model, and if the user changes the input, it will update the model.   This doesn't actually stop you from doing anything you want to do... I'm just not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here's an (silly) example of updating the value of the input based on a timer: http://jsfiddle.net/PpaQ7/1/

Comment: daCoda, if you wanted for some reason to have something happen when an element is initialized but have that code in the view you could use ng-init="expression" however I believe it's just not best practices to do so.  You want to keep your view clean of logic that may need to be tested.  The view should simply bind to the model, the controller should update the model and the view will automatically reflect this.  If you include logic in your view then the view has to be available to test the controller (things are tightly coupled which is bad, makes the code less portable/testable).

Comment: Thanks for your info guys. I liked your explanation of two-way binding Karl.

Comment: The textbox I am currently working on has an initial value, as well as an ng-model... and they both work (which is something I couldn't replicate on JSFiddle). I am assuming that this 'error' (of having a value AND an ng-model) is something that is automatically 'forgiven' and 'fixed' by the browser, for noob programmers like me.

Comment: Right. Basically, just don't include a `value` attribute in markup. Set the `ng-model` in markup, and set the initial and future values of that model in script, inside of your controller.